# Dataframe not able to write on S3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am creating a dataframe from existing hive table.Table is partitioned on date and site column.Now, when i am trying to overwrite the data in this same table after some computation with previous day data.It is successfully getting loaded.

But when i am trying to write final dataframe at S3 bucket. I am getting error saying file not found.Now the file it is mentioning is previous day file which is now overwritten.

If i write dataframe first and then overwrite table then its running fine.

For writing at S3 location , what it has to do with table partition file?

Below is the error and code.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory: s3://bucket_1/DM/web_fact_tbl/local_dt=2018-05-10/site_name=ABC/part-00000-882a6e29-eb6a-477c-8b88-6fe853956674.c000

```
fact_tbl = spark.table('db.web_fact_tbl')
fact_lkp = fact_tbl.filter(fact_tbl['local_dt']=='2018-05-10')
fact_join = fact_lkp.alias('a').join(fact_tbl.alias('b'),(col('a.id') == col('b.id')),"inner").select('a.*')
fact_final = fact_join.union(fact_tbl)
fact_final.coalesce(2).createOrReplaceTempView('cwf')
spark.sql('INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE dm.web_fact_tbl PARTITION (local_dt, site_name) \
                           SELECT * FROM cwf')
fact_final.write.csv('s3://bucket_1/yahoo')
```

Comment: I understand in-place writes are not safe. This answer explains the why and a way to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49842311/5189811

Comment: I have not much idea about AWS but one thing I want to know that if you r partition name is local_dt and site_name it should be there in you hdfs path right?

Comment: Are you removing the partitions manually?

Comment: @JaishreeRout Its S3 location and external table path and write path are different

Comment: @MaheshKalani, ok I donot have much idea about this. You can tag Amazon-s3 to this question. You may get more and quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Before last line `fact_final` is just a "lazy" dataframe object that contains definitions only. It does not contain any data. But it has pointer to exact data files, where data is stored actually.

When you try to perform actual operations (does not matter it's writing to S3, or executing query like `fact_final.count()`) you'll get the error as above. It looks like partition `local_dt=2018-05-10` does not exists anymore (files/folder that sits behind it does not exists).

You can try to re-initialize dataframe once again, before final write (it's another lazy operation - all work is done in your case while you writing it on S3).

Comment: Partition is there but table file is getting overwritten before final data frame is written at S3. But my question is what is final dataframe has to do with table partitions.

Comment: is that exact file exists?

Comment: maybe you should try to read dataframe once again, after overwrite?

Comment: That file got over written with new data ..so file with new name is now there. But table overwrite and data frame write are different then why problem is coming in dataframe write

Comment: I think my answer address your question "why problem is coming in dataframe write"

Comment: if you replace last line with `fact_final.count()`, I reckon you'll see the same error

Comment: Absolutely correct mate... thanks ..its giving same error. What can be solution?

Comment: Updated answer.